# Unset store from product

Tags: attributes, collection, multistore, product-collection

I have product or a collection of around 18000 products who are assigned to different stores. I need to unset some of them(not too less), from 1 or 2 of these stores. Is there a way I can make a script to unset Store id programmatically.

Comment: not directly an answer to your question but Magento has some functionality that you can unset products from store from Catalog. you can search for your products (something they have in common), click select all  and from actions Update Attributes

Comment: I am aware but as I said they are not too few, I mean they may be around 14000+ products, so it is a lot of time consuming task

Comment: Time consuming for the server, but not necessarily for you. "Select all" selects all matching items, not only those visible on the current page

Comment: Question still remains, on how to unset the store

Comment: To update I have already tried : $actionModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_action');
$actionModel->updateWebsites($productIds, $websiteIds, 'remove');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

$write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

$deletStore = "DELETE FROM `mage_catalog_product_website` WHERE `product_id` = ".$data->getData('product_id')." AND `website_id` = 2";

$write->query($deletStore);
```

This worked for me